# Split list of dataframes and return separate list entries instead of sublists

Tags: r, list, split

I have a list of dataframes that I would like to split based on a column, in that case the `cluster` column.

```
d1 <- data.frame(y1=c(1,2,3), cluster=c(1,2,6))
d2 <- data.frame(y1=c(3,2,1), cluster=c(6,2,4))

my.list <- list(d1, d2)
```

Using
`lapply(my.list , function(x) split(x, x$cluster))` returns the splitted dataframes as sublists. Is it possible to split the dataframes and create new dataframes as separate list entries?

The desired output would be something like this:

```
my.list2 <- list(df1_cl1 , df1_cl2m df1_cl6, df2_cl6, df2_cl2, df2_cl4 )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step is correct, to get data in required structure you can `unlist` the list output with `recursive = FALSE`.

```
my.list2  <- unlist(lapply(my.list , function(x) 
                    split(x, x$cluster)), recursive = FALSE)

my.list2
#$`1`
#  y1 cluster
#1  1       1

#$`2`
#  y1 cluster
#2  2       2

#$`6`
#  y1 cluster
#3  3       6

#$`2`
#  y1 cluster
#2  2       2

#$`4`
#  y1 cluster
#3  1       4

#$`6`
#  y1 cluster
#1  3       6

length(my.list2)
#[1] 6
```

You can drop the names of the list with `unname(my.list2)`.

Comment: If the list was a list of tibbles and I just want the tibbles to be "released" from the list, but I don't have an f level because the tibbles are already named:  base::split(my.list, **f = ** %>% 
set_names(paste("y", names(.), sep = "_")) %>% list2env(globalenv())
How would you do it?

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, based on `dplyr:group_split` and  `purrr::map`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

map(my.list, ~ group_split(.x, .x$cluster, .keep = F)) %>% flatten

#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>      y1 cluster
#>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1     1       1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>      y1 cluster
#>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1     2       2
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>      y1 cluster
#>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1     3       6
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>      y1 cluster
#>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1     2       2
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>      y1 cluster
#>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1     1       4
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>      y1 cluster
#>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1     3       6
```